# Merge sort from "Programming Scala" causes stack overflow

Tags: scala, recursion, stack-overflow

A direct cut and paste of the following algorithm:

```
def msort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean)
            (xs: List[T]): List[T] = {
  def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] =
    (xs, ys) match {
      case (Nil, _) => ys
      case (_, Nil) => xs
      case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
        if (less(x, y)) x :: merge(xs1, ys)
        else y :: merge(xs, ys1)
    }
  val n = xs.length / 2
  if (n == 0) xs
  else {
    val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n
     merge(msort(less)(ys), msort(less)(zs))
  }
}
```

causes a StackOverflowError on 5000 long lists.

Is there any way to optimize this so that this doesn't occur?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is doing this because it isn't tail-recursive. You can fix this by either using a non-strict collection, or by making it tail-recursive.

The latter solution goes like this:

```
def msort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean) 
            (xs: List[T]): List[T] = { 
  def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T], acc: List[T]): List[T] = 
    (xs, ys) match { 
      case (Nil, _) => ys.reverse ::: acc 
      case (_, Nil) => xs.reverse ::: acc
      case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) => 
        if (less(x, y)) merge(xs1, ys, x :: acc) 
        else merge(xs, ys1, y :: acc) 
    } 
  val n = xs.length / 2 
  if (n == 0) xs 
  else { 
    val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n 
    merge(msort(less)(ys), msort(less)(zs), Nil).reverse
  } 
}
```

Using non-strictness involves either passing parameters by-name, or using non-strict collections such as `Stream`. The following code uses `Stream` just to prevent stack overflow, and `List` elsewhere:

```
def msort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean) 
            (xs: List[T]): List[T] = { 
  def merge(left: List[T], right: List[T]): Stream[T] = (left, right) match {
    case (x :: xs, y :: ys) if less(x, y) => Stream.cons(x, merge(xs, right))
    case (x :: xs, y :: ys) => Stream.cons(y, merge(left, ys))
    case _ => if (left.isEmpty) right.toStream else left.toStream
  }
  val n = xs.length / 2 
  if (n == 0) xs 
  else { 
    val (ys, zs) = xs splitAt n 
    merge(msort(less)(ys), msort(less)(zs)).toList
  } 
}
```

Comment: I thought about trying to make it tail recursive, then saw quite a lot of info claiming that the JVM isn't that amenable and doesn't always optimize tail recursion. Is there some sort of guideline for when this succeeds?

Comment: The JVM doesn't, so the Scala compiler will do it for you. It only does under certain requirements: it must be self-recursion (ie, f calling g, and g calling f won't work), it must be _tail_ recursion, of course (the recursive call _must_ always be the last thing on that code path), on methods it must be either `final` or `private`. In the example, because `merge` is defined inside `msort`, instead of being defined on a class or object, it is effectively private.

Comment: I think it might be worth mentioning here that msort itself is not tail recursive, but merge is. For anyone only convinced by the compiler, add @tailrec to the definition of merge, and you will notice it's getting accepted as a tail recursive function, just as Daniel outlined.

Comment: Now, having said that, it's also important to note that msort not being tail-recursive is not going to be a real problem. It will recurse only log2(n) levels deep, with n being the number of elements in the list getting passed in. So for a list of 5000 elements, msort will recurse only 13 levels deep.

Comment: @Wilfred `merge` cannot be tail recursive, because this isn't a tail call: `x :: merge(xs1, ys)`. A bug was found with `tailrec` code, but it doesn't look like it should apply here, so I find it curious that `tailrec` isn't complaining.

Comment: @Daniel I was talking about your implementation. Yours doesn't have x :: merge(xs1, ys).

Comment: Can you explain a bit please about why you had to .reverse twice, and is there a way to avoid it? sorry but it wasn't obvious to me, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just playing around with scala's `TailCalls` (trampolining support), which I suspect wasn't around when this question was originally posed.  Here's a recursive immutable version of the merge in [Rex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202815/24283).

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def merge[T <% Ordered[T]](x:List[T],y:List[T]):List[T] = {

  def build(s:List[T],a:List[T],b:List[T]):TailRec[List[T]] = {
    if (a.isEmpty) {
      done(b.reverse ::: s)
    } else if (b.isEmpty) {
      done(a.reverse ::: s)
    } else if (a.head<b.head) {
      tailcall(build(a.head::s,a.tail,b))
    } else {
      tailcall(build(b.head::s,a,b.tail))
    }
  }

  build(List(),x,y).result.reverse
}
```

Runs just as fast as the mutable version on big `List[Long]`s on Scala 2.9.1 on 64bit OpenJDK (Debian/Squeeze amd64 on an i7).

Answer (score 3):

Just in case Daniel's solutions didn't make it clear enough, the problem is that merge's recursion is as deep as the length of the list, and it's not tail-recursion so it can't be converted into iteration.

Scala can convert Daniel's tail-recursive merge solution into something approximately equivalent to this:

```
def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = {
  var acc:List[T] = Nil
  var decx = xs
  var decy = ys
  while (!decx.isEmpty || !decy.isEmpty) {
    (decx, decy) match { 
      case (Nil, _) => { acc = decy.reverse ::: acc ; decy = Nil }
      case (_, Nil) => { acc = decx.reverse ::: acc ; decx = Nil }
      case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) => 
        if (less(x, y)) { acc = x :: acc ; decx = xs1 }
        else { acc = y :: acc ; decy = ys1 }
    }
  }
  acc.reverse
}
```

but it keeps track of all the variables for you.

(A tail-recursive method is one where the method *only* calls itself to get a complete answer to pass back; it never calls itself and then does something with the result before passing it back.  Also, tail-recursion can't be used if the method might be polymorphic, so it generally only works in objects or with classes marked final.)

Comment: Should that last acc actually be acc.reverse ?  If you were using this as a standalone merge function there should be, but maybe there's something about msort's usage I don't get.