# StackOverflowError for mergesort in scala

Tags: scala, recursion, scala-2.10

I have implemented the below mergesort code. But I get stackOverFlowError in the merge procedure of the algorithm when the no of integers is as high as 100000. I'm using pattern matching with recursion for the merge procedure. I understand using recursion for the merge procedure is not optimal given that the depth for this input would be as high as 50000. But since I'm using scala I was expecting some compiler optimization to make the recursive calls iterative since these are tail recursive calls. Can you please help me understand why I still get StackOverFlowerror in the below code?  Please provide input on how I can write this more effeciently in scala?
Below is the code:

```
package common

object Merge {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("IntegerArray.txt")
    val data = source.getLines.map {line => line.toInt}.toList
    println(data.length)
    val res = mergeSort(data)
    println(res)
  }
  def mergeSort(data: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if(data.length <= 1) {data }
    else {
      val mid = (data.length)/2
      val (l, r) = data.splitAt(mid)
      val l1 = mergeSort(l)
      val l2 = mergeSort(r)
      merge(l1, l2)
    }
  }

  def merge(l: List[Int], r: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    l match {
      case List() => r
      case x::xs => {
        r match {
          case List() => l
          case y::ys => {
            if(x<y) {
              x :: merge(xs, r)
            } else {
              y :: merge(l, ys)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:30)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:30)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:30)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:30)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:30)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:30)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:30)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:30)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:32)
    at common.Merge$.merge(Merge.scala:30)
```

Comment: Eh, no, these are not tail-recursive calls. The tail call is the call to `::.apply`.

Comment: Take a look at the top related question for how to make it tail-recursive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201472/merge-sort-from-programming-scala-causes-stack-overflow?rq=1

Comment: If you have " x :: merge(xs, r)" in the merge method, then that's NOT tail-recursive. A tail-recursive call would be merge(a, b) within merge, not the call to merge being one of the operands to another operation. This cannot be optimized to a loop, it will remain recursive and possibly blow the stack, which you already experienced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge sort needs to be recursive but that isn't a problem as it is O(log n). The `merge` method should be optimized to a loop as it is O(n).

TailRec optimization only works when the recursive call is the last command, in your case the last command is a list concatenation (or prepend).

You can add `@tailrec` annotation. The compiler will always try to optimize but this way it will let you know if it can't do it.

```
  merge(l1, l2, Nil)
  ...

  @tailrec
  def merge(l: List[Int], r: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    l match {
      case List() => acc ::: r
      case x::xs => {
        r match {
          case List() => acc ::: l
          case y::ys => {
            val (item, lTail, rTail) =
               if(x<y) (x, xs, r)
               else (y, l, ys)
            merge(lTail, rTail, acc:::List(item))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The strategy is to use an accumulator for the result and in the base case return the accumulator instead of a Nil list. That way the compiler can make a TailRec optimization.

Also consider writing the code like this:

```
  @tailrec
  def merge(l: List[Int], r: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if (l.isEmpty) acc ::: r
    else if (r.isEmpty) acc ::: l
    else {
      val (item, lTail, rTail) =
        if (l.head<r.head) (l.head, l.tail, r)
        else (r.head, l, r.tail)
      merge(lTail, rTail, acc:::List(item))
    }
  }
```

I find this way simpler and easier to understand.

Also note that the tail recursive call doesn't need to be only one at the end as shown in the previous examples, so you can return to your previous if-else calls as long as the recursive calls are the last of each branch:

```
  @tailrec
  def merge(l: List[Int], r: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if (l.isEmpty) acc ::: r
    else if (r.isEmpty) acc ::: l
    else {
      if (l.head < r.head)
        merge(l.tail, r, acc ::: List(l.head))
      else
        merge(l, r.tail, acc ::: List(r.head))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also match on tuples:

```
def merge(l: List[Int], r: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = (l,r) match {
    case (lh :: lt, rh :: rt) => 
        if (lh < rh) 
             merge(lt, r, lh :: acc) 
        else 
             merge(l, rt, rh :: acc)
    case _ => acc.reverse ::: l ::: r
}
```

If you accumulate in reverse, your running time won't be dependent on how efficient `:::` is implemented and you'll get your `O(n)`

Comment: How is this more effecient? even here it depends on ::: right?

Comment: @PrathikPuthran This way the `:::` and reverse are only applied at the base case, so if `:::` is O(n) you still get an O(n) merge instead of an O(n*n).