# in place mergsort with Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting

How can I sort in place an array and list with Scala?

In particular I would like to know how can I do this efficiently in a functional way.

I have seen various implementation of the merge sort in scala but they relies on trick that make the algorithm much slower.

Comment: you want to implement it yourself, right?

Comment: have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2201472/3248346

Comment: @I.K. but he mentioned he wanted to sort *in place*, right?

Comment: yes I do not want to use external libraries

Comment: In-place mergesort is a really tricky algorithm to get right, functional or no.  It's way easier if you can have swap space.

Comment: Surely there is a contradiction between "functional programming" and "sort in-place". At least, as I understand "functional programming", it excludes mutable datastructures.

Comment: I am not a scala expert. Do you think it is bad to do an in place sort in a a functional programming way? I think that should be something reasonable to ask.